# Attribute error using __builtin__ functions inside class method

Tags: python, linux, namespaces, built-in

I installed rdiff-backup on my arch linux box only to end up with the attribute error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'reduce'
```

The error exists in one of rdiff_backup classes, but I can not spot the error. The function `reduce` should be builtin, and I can not get the code to find the function.

The code from rdiff looks like this:

```
    def get_total_dest_size_change(self):
        """Return total destination size change

        This represents the total change in the size of the
        rdiff-backup destination directory.

        """
        addvals = [self.NewFileSize, self.ChangedSourceSize,
                           self.IncrementFileSize]
        subtractvals = [self.DeletedFileSize, self.ChangedMirrorSize]
        for val in addvals + subtractvals:
                if val is None:
                        result = None
                        break
        else:
                def addlist(l): return reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, l)
                result = addlist(addvals) - addlist(subtractvals)
        self.TotalDestinationSizeChange = result
        return result
```

And the error occurs in the locally defined addlist function.
I've tried to import the builtin module in the top of the file (statistics.py), both like

```
import __builtin__
```

and

```
from __builtin__ import reduce
```

and tried to change the namespace of the method like so:

```
def addlist(l): return __builtin__.reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, l)
```

But alas. Still the same error.

I've not been able to find any good information or solution so far, so maybe someone with a little tighter knowledge about python could take stab at it.

Thanks
m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, l)` is an equivalent of `sum(l)`. Can you try whether `sum(l)` works? Also, which python version are you using (`sum` is available in version >= 2.3)

Comment: That actually seemed to fix the problem. I think its very strange and a little bothersome that it is able to call `sum` but not `reduce`. Do you know why? I use python 2.7. Thanks!

Comment: That was just a quick hack that came to my head:). I do not know what causes the problem with `reduce`, it looks like it is not in current namespace there...But even shadowing it with another `reduce` declaration would give different error. Maybe you should file a bug to the rdiff-backup people.